# Assign a new value to variables by using method in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

In Java, I can use [class-name].[method] to change the value of variables in a class like:

```
 public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        test.teste();
        test.printlnvar();
    }        
}

class test{
    public static int a = 0;
    public static int b = 0;
    public static void teste(){
        a = 9;
        b = 12;
    }
    public static void printlnvar(){
        System.out.println("the value of A: " + a);
        System.out.println("the value of B: " + b);
    }
}
```

However, how can I do that in Kotlin? I try but the result is always 0 for variable IntColumn and IntRow in code below:

```
public class drawTriangle{       
   public var IntColumn:Int = 0;
   public var IntRow:Int = 0;

  fun drawTriangle(){
    this.inputRowandColumn();
    this.Printvalue();
  }

  fun inputRowandColumn(){
    IntColumn = 12;
    IntRow = 3;
  }

  fun Printvalue(){
    println("the value of rows is: ${IntRow}");
    println("the value of column is: ${IntColumn}");
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){
    drawTriangle().inputRowandColumn();
    drawTriangle().Printvalue();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `main` function you create 2 separate instances of the `drawTriangle` class, thus there are 2 sets of variables - one of them you change, one of them you print. A short fix:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val d = drawTriangle()
    d.inputRowandColumn()
    d.Printvalue()
}
```

P.S. Your Kotlin code drastically differs from your Java code. In your Java snippet you use 2 `static` fields, which belong to a class. But in the Kotlin snippet you use 2 member properties, which need instances to be stored in.

P.P.S. Your Kotlin code kinda looks like C#. When learning a new language it is not a bad idea to use the naming conventions of that language ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're doing what you're doing. As per voddan, your code is not equivalent. Java is using statics, which are associated with the class, and not an instance, hence your ability to access them directly from the static 'main' method.

Kotlin separates class (static) items from instance items. If you define a class, you can only instantiate instances and work with them.

If you truly want to implement your attempt in Kotlin, you need to use an 'object' rather than a 'class'. An object in Kotlin is a singleton. Here's how you would write it in Kotlin.

```
object drawTriangle {
    var intColumn: Int = 0
    var intRow: Int = 0

    fun drawTriangle() {
        this.inputRowandColumn()
        this.printvalue()
    }

    fun inputRowandColumn() {
        intColumn = 12
        intRow = 3
    }

    fun printvalue() {
        println("the value of Rows is: $intRow")
        println("the value of Column is: $intColumn")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    drawTriangle.inputRowandColumn()
    drawTriangle.printvalue()
}
```

Note that I removed the 'public' as Kotlin's default is public. Removed semi-colons, and renamed things to conform to Kotlin naming standards.